# Change values in specific columns in a workbook with Multiple ExcelSheet using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a workbook named CustomerSales with two Excel worksheets named sheet1 and sheet2 in both sheets I need to write/change values in particular column values so I used.

```
if (data.at[g, 'failedColumn'] == '' and data.at[g, 'reason'] == ''):
    data.at[g, 'status'] = 'Fail'
    data.at[g, 'failedColumn'] = 'BUKRS'
    data.at[g, 'reason'] = 'Customer Not Extended To Any Company code'
    data.to_excel(variable)//*variable-path to excel file
```

Here data is Dataframe of sheet1 here the code works perfectly fine resultexcel file has updated column values
[image]

But when I am trying above code with dataframe of sheet2 existing sheet1 data get replaced by sheet2. Is there a way I can change both sheets values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate the data in both of the sheets you should read the file with pandas, create 2 separate dataframes (one for each sheet) and then save them in the same workbook using xlsxwriter. Here is a demo code:

```
 import pandas as pd

## Read the 2 sheets as separate dataframes
df1 = pd.read_excel('name_of_your_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('name_of_your_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

# Do all of your data manipulation here

# Start using xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('name_of_the_new_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Save each df to separate sheet in the same file
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)

# You can format your worksheets here

# Finally save the file
writer.save()
```